# Get value-of in XSL, XML same names

Tags: xml, xslt, nested-attributes

Been toying with this for some time...
I have an xml file with the following lines

```
<image size="small">image_small.jpg</image>
<image size="medium">image_medium.jpg</image>
<image size="large">image_large.jpg</image>
```

ANy ideas on how I can just get the medium url for example.

currently I have... but its not doing the trick

```
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="image/@size[@size=medium]" />
         </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very well defined since we don't have your whole XSLT nor the desired output, but I'll give it a try:

If you are using a for-loop to iterate over the different images you need to set your constraints on the loop itself, not the content of the loop.

If you put your example code inside a `xsl:for-each` it will iterate over every image but only fill the `@src` attribute when the `image` with `@size="medium"` is the current node. That would give you three table rows with three images but only one image with a valid `@src` attribute.

Instead change your `xsl:for-each` ([or use `xsl:apply-templates`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460232/differences-between-for-each-and-templates-in-xsl)) to only iterate over your images with `@size="medium"`:

```
<!-- This will only iterate over the medium sized images. -->
<xsl:for-each select="image[@size='medium']">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="{.}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Another tip:** instead of using `xsl:attribute` use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template).