# trying to avoid xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

Assuming I have an xml.document like this (not complete):

```
<root>
<elem id="1"/>
<elem id="2"/>
<elem id="3"/>
</root>
```

and I access it via the doc-function, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="curDoc" select="doc(iri-to-uri("abc.xml"))"/>
```

now I want to compare each element in the document that I apply the stylesheet to with each element from that abc.xml.

The document I apply the stylesheet to looks like this:

```
<node>
<somenode id="1"/>
<somenode id="2"/>
<somenode id="3"/>
</node>
```

Now the elements in both documents are actually not in order!

Is there another way to do this than the following:

```
<xsl:template match="somenode">
<xsl:variable name="curElem" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="$curDoc/root/elem">
<xsl:if test="@id = $curElem[@id]">
<!-- do something -->
<xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I read a lot that you should avoid for-each and just use the template mechanism, but how could I do this here without for-each (using XSLT 2.0)?

Comment: `xsl:for-each` doesn't always have to be avoided, it should not be treated as if it's a 'for' loop in a procedural language context

Comment: @DanField In this case though it can easily be avoided.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4462752/423105 on why for-each is sometimes better than apply-templates. It exists for a good reason, and simply avoiding it all the time is not always a "best practice." Even better, read Jeni Tennison: http://www.jenitennison.com/2007/05/01/matching-templates-named-templates-or-for-each-my-rules-of-thumb.html

Comment: @LarsH That's fair enough, the only thing I wouldn't agree with is that `for-each` is easier to read. And it's just as easy to make fragile assumptions with for-each too. However I agree you shouldn't avoid it for avoidance's sake.

Comment: @biziclop I'm happy to discuss this but I think the discussion belongs on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460232/differences-between-for-each-and-templates-in-xsl/4462752#4462752

Comment: What is exactly is the purpose of these comparisons? It's quite likely it could be achieved without going over each possible combination of two nodes - regardless of how *that* would be done, be it a template or a for-each.

Answer (score 2):

Move the condition into the `<for-each>` select.

```
<xsl:template match="somenode">
  <xsl:variable name="currentElementId" select="./@id"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$curDoc/root/elem[@id = $currentElementId]">
    <!-- do something -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This solution still uses the loop. It is correct because the node list could be empty or you could have several `elem` elements with the same `id` attribute value.

In XML the attribute `id` is not necessarily unique, it depends on the document definition (DTD, XSD, ...).

Most functions use the first node in a list so it should work without the for-each, actually.

```
<xsl:template match="somenode">
  <xsl:variable name="currentElementId" select="./@id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="targetNode" select="$curDoc/root/elem[@id = $currentElementId]">
  <xsl:if test="$targetNode">
    <!-- do something with $targetNode -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

xsl:for-each is not intrinsically evil. It's just that excessive use of xsl:for-each (and xsl:if) is often a symptom of a programmer who hasn't mastered the more powerful constructs in the language.

Looking at your code, you are actually doing a join, and the best way to do a join in XSLT is to use keys. So I would write this as

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="elem" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="somenode">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('id', @id, $curdoc)">
    <!-- do something -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You could replace the xsl:for-each with an xsl:apply-templates, perhaps in a specific mode, but I wouldn't do it unless there is some reason, e.g. an expectation that someone might want one day to substitute your "do something" with "do something different".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example how what you want can be done without using an `<xsl:for-each>` instruction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc">
        <root>
            <elem id="1"/>
            <elem id="2"/>
            <elem id="3"/>
        </root> 
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="somenode">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc/*/elem[@id eq current()/@id]">
      <xsl:with-param name="porigElem" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elem">
    <xsl:param name="porigElem" as="element()"/>
    Match:
      Original: <xsl:sequence select="$porigElem"/>
      Matching: <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document (reordered, to match the description of the problem):

```
<node>
    <somenode id="3"/>
    <somenode id="1"/>
    <somenode id="2"/>
</node>
```

The wanted, correct result is produced:

```
Match:
  Original: <somenode id="3"/>
  Matching: <elem id="3"/>

Match:
  Original: <somenode id="1"/>
  Matching: <elem id="1"/>

Match:
  Original: <somenode id="2"/>
  Matching: <elem id="2"/>
```

Of course, if one wants to use keys, as recommended in the answer of Dr. Kay, the key must be defined, and then the applying of templates will look like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kelemById', @id, $vDoc)">
  <xsl:with-param name="porigElem" select="."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The complete transformation now is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kelemById" match="elem" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc">
        <root>
            <elem id="1"/>
            <elem id="2"/>
            <elem id="3"/>
        </root> 
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="somenode">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kelemById', @id, $vDoc)">
      <xsl:with-param name="porigElem" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elem">
    <xsl:param name="porigElem" as="element()"/>
    Match:
      Original: <xsl:sequence select="$porigElem"/>
      Matching: <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and when this transformation is applied on the same source XML document, the same wanted and correct result is produced.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure if this is nicer, but that should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="somenode">
     <xsl:variable name="curElem" select="."/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$curDoc" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/elem">
        <xsl:if test="@id = $curElem[@id]">
           test
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the variable defined in one template will be visible in the other?

Comment: No, a variable defined in one template is not visible in another. However, you could pass $curElem as a parameter to the next template using `<xsl:with-param>`.

Comment: Please test code before submitting it as an answer. Thanks!