# How to use multiple template with different match in the same XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use an XSLT on XML file to convert it into another XML file. 
This is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:og="http://og.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no"
        indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="_source/extension">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="MT">
            <xsl:attribute name="N" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="V" select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <GSP>
            <xsl:attribute name="VER">
                <xsl:value-of select="3.2" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="root">
                <TM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(floor(took) div floor(1000))" />
                </TM>

                <RES>
                    <M>
                        <xsl:value-of select="floor(hits/total)" />
                    </M>
                    <xsl:for-each select="hits/hits">
                        <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_first" as="node()"
                            select="_source" />
                        <R>
                            <xsl:attribute name="N">
                            <xsl:number format="0" level="single" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <U>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/U)))" />
                            </U>
                            <UE>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/UE)))" />
                            </UE>
                            <UD>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/UD)))" />
                            </UD>
                            <T>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string($var1_resultof_first/T)" />
                            </T>
                            <Last-Modified>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(_source/submitTime,'T')" /> 
                            </Last-Modified>
                            <S>
                                <xsl:for-each select="highlight/newContent">
                                    <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)" />
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </S>

                        </R>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RES>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </GSP>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has two template.One which matches to

```
<xsl:template match="_source/extension">
```

and the other which matches to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

But when I run this XSLT for my input XML, only the above template is being appied on my XML

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
```

The other match(_source/match) is not applied. Can we use multiple template in the same XSLT? I might be missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

Of course only the `match="/"` template is applied to your XML. It matches the root node and never calls any other template, so the fact that no other template is ever called should not come as a surprise.

For better results, drop every `<xsl:for-each>` from your code and replace it with `<xsl:apply-templates>` and the appropriate, matching templates. `<xsl:for-each>` has its uses, but none of them occur in your use case.

Like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <GSP VER="3.2">
        <xsl:apply-templates match="root" />
    </GSP>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <TM>
        <!-- floor(1000) is... 1000. Maybe you mean something else? -->
        <xsl:value-of select="floor(took) div floor(1000)" />
    </TM>
    <RES>
        <M><xsl:value-of select="floor(hits/total)" /></M>
        <xsl:apply-templates="hits/hits" />
    </RES>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hits/hits">
    <R>
        <xsl:attribute name="N">
            <xsl:number format="0" level="single" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- you could use select="_source/U,_source/UE,_source/UT" here, too -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="_source/U" mode="URI" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="_source/UE" mode="URI" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="_source/UD" mode="URI" />
        <T><xsl:value-of select="_source/T" /></T>
        <Last-Modified>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(_source/submitTime,'T')" /> 
        </Last-Modified>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="highlight/newContent" />
    </R>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="URI">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:anyURI(.)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="highlight/newContent">
    <S><xsl:value-of select="." /></S>
</xsl:template>
```

Aim for short, focused templates that do one thing.

Call your `_source/extension` template in there at the right place using `<xsl:apply-templates>`. Remove the `<xsl:for-each>` from that template, too.

Read [What are the differences between 'call-template' and 'apply-templates' in XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478045/what-are-the-differences-between-call-template-and-apply-templates-in-xsl) and [For loops vs. apply-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342902/for-loops-vs-apply-templates) and [differences between for-each and templates in xsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460232/differences-between-for-each-and-templates-in-xsl), among other similar posts, for further detail about how templates work in XSLT.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at these links.